# connecting to network with openvpn on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I'm running ubuntu desktop verion Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.  I installed openvpn by running

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

I then try to connect to my vpn by running

```
sudo openvpn --config client.ovpn
```

and I get the error message below when I input my login and password.

I found a related link:

https://superuser.com/questions/1737052/openssl-error0a00018essl-routinesca-md-too-weak

I tried creating an openvpn.cnf file under etc/openvpn/ as suggested, but still got the same error.

I also tried adding the line suggested in the link

tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"

to the openssl.cnf under /etc/ssl/

In both cases I still get the same error shown below.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

error:

```
2023-10-01 16:40:49 WARNING: Compression for receiving enabled. Compression has been used in the past to break encryption. Sent packets are not compressed unless "allow-compression yes" is also set.
2023-10-01 16:40:49 DEPRECATED OPTION: --cipher set to 'AES-128-CBC' but missing in --data-ciphers (AES-256-GCM:AES-128-GCM). Future OpenVPN version will ignore --cipher for cipher negotiations. Add 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers or change --cipher 'AES-128-CBC' to --data-ciphers-fallback 'AES-128-CBC' to silence this warning.
2023-10-01 16:40:49 OpenVPN 2.5.5 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 14 2022
2023-10-01 16:40:49 library versions: OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022, LZO 2.10
Enter Auth Username: myusername
 Enter Auth Password: ********                
2023-10-01 16:41:06 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
2023-10-01 16:41:06 OpenSSL: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak
2023-10-01 16:41:06 Cannot load inline certificate file
2023-10-01 16:41:06 Exiting due to fatal error
```

update:

I tried adding the line below to the .ovpn file:

```
tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"
```

and logging in.  Now I get the message below over and over but when I try to ssh in to my server the connection times out.  So don't think the vpn connection is working.

message after logging in:

```
2023-10-02 16:41:07 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
2023-10-02 16:41:07 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]73.15.233.200:1194
2023-10-02 16:41:07 UDP link local: (not bound)
2023-10-02 16:41:07 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]73.15.233.200:1194
2023-10-02 16:42:08 [UNDEF] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
2023-10-02 16:42:08 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
2023-10-02 16:42:13 WARNING: --ns-cert-type is DEPRECATED.  Use --remote-cert-tls instead.
```

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but I had to put the line `tls-cipher "DEFAULT:@SECLEVEL=0"` in my .ovpn file, not in the `openssl.conf` in order to connect to some vpn providers that have not updated their systems.

Comment: If your details are correct and you're still using Ubuntu 22.04.1, then I support you apply security fixes asap to your system. A correctly upgraded 22.04 system will report itself as 22.04.3, and hasn't reported itself as 22.04.1 for a long time (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/02/24/ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-released/ shows the ISO release of 22.04.2, but installed systems upgraded in the weeks before ISO release!).  Your provided details maybe posted incorrectly (some package versions always say 22.04.1 when updated - but not your release detail), or maybe you're using Ubuntu based but check.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I tried adding the line you suggested to my .ovpn file.  It still doesn't seem to be connecting on the vpn.  I've added the new error messages I'm getting to the original post as an update.